# Where does the value of the PayPal IPN product_name field come from?

Tags: paypal-ipn

I've been receiving PayPal IPNs for recurring donations.  The IPNs include a field called **product_name** and I'm unable to find much information about that field from the PayPal documentation.  I'm looking for information on the source of the field value, preferably from official documentation if it's available.

I'm using PayPal Payments Standard. The donation form is my own HTML using the variables from the [HTML Variables page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/).  The **cmd** field is set to the value **_donations** so that patrons can enter their own donation amount.  The **product_name** field is not included in my form and is not listed on the HTML variables page.

The [IPN and PDT Variables page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/IPNandPDTVariables/) uses a circular description for the **product_name** field that I didn't find helpful.  In particular, I could not find how PayPal determines what value to use for the field.  According to the IPN and PDT Variables page page, the **product_name** field is only used for recurring payments (as opposed to one-time donations).

From trial and error, it looks like the **product_name** field of the IPN is being populated from the **item_name** field of my HTML donations form. But I'm reluctant to code my IPN listener using undocumented features. I'd feel more secure being able to refer to PayPal documentation to know for sure how the **product_name** value is determined.

Would anyone know where the value of the IPN **product_name** field comes from and maybe be able to refer me to documentation where I can read up on the details?

Answer (score 0):

> it looks like the product_name field of the IPN is being populated from the item_name field of my HTML donations form.

Yes.